# how to change the kde4 plasma desktop to folder view for all users

Tags: desktop, kde4, plasma

I see there is one solution for individual user, https://centosfaq.org/centos/how-do-i-default-to-folder-view-in-my-custom-kde-user-profile/, and my question is, how to change that for all users? is there any setting system level configure file? Thanks!

ps. i run the "kde4-config --path config", and it shows below paths,

```
[root@New122 kde]# kde4-config --path config
/root/.kde/share/config/:/etc/kde/:/usr/share/kde-settings/kde-profile/default/share/config/:/usr/share/config/
```

I searched aboved paths, but no clue is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folderview setting is located in a file called `plasma-desktop-appletsrc` which can be found under `~/.kde/share/config`.

You ran `kde4-config --path config` as root, so it returned `/root/.kde/share/config` since that is the config location for root home. You would get a different result for every user, with `~/.kde/share/config` being an entry (where `~` represents the current user's home directory).

In `plasma-desktop-appletsrc` there are a lot of different settings that define how the desktop is set up. The setting for folderview should be under `[Containments][X]` where X is a number e.g. `[Containments][64]` is what I have on my system. If the desktop layout is set to `Default Desktop` then what will appear is `plugin=desktop` and changing that to `plugin=folderview` and restarting the plasma-desktop process (or logging out and back in) should update it.

Now, the unfortunate thing is that I do not believe there is a way to do this for every user in one command. You could write a script that iterates over user homes and uses sed to update `plugin=desktop` to `plugin=folderview`. But as far as I know there is no kde configuration command that would update everyone's home to use the folderview.

In the event that the other users home directories have not yet been created, you could create an `/etc/skel/.kde/share/config/plasma-applets-desktop` that has the "correct" information in it so that when a user first logs in the file would be created as defined in`/etc/skel` with `folderview` already set.